# How to show a specific table from an HTML file with several tables when the html is called?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I have an HTML file with five tables in it. I don't know how to call a specific table when I need it. Example, I need only the second table from the five tables in my HTML file when I call the html file. Thanks in advance..

Comment: what is your trigger to call the table and also the file? Include what you had tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to show/hide table you can use below code

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">  


<!--  
function show(id)  
{  
     if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none')  
     {  
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';  
     }  
}  
//-->  

<!--  
function hide(id)  
{  
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';  

}  
//-->  
</script>
```

By default you can assign id and have values like below

```
  <table id="tblA" style="DISPLAY: none" cols="1" cellpadding="2">
```

Comment: Hi. I was able to hide the tables. How can I be able to call and display a selected table on the html link.

Comment: Using the  show(id)  function . It written above . Just call the function with the table id .. If you want to hide it again then call hide(id) function